# Are all versions of code available when I push to github

Tags: git, github

I'm still new with git, so please correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology.

I want to push a project to github. However, when I initialized the project, I added some files with sensitive information (database passwords). I have since removed the files and commited the change.

If I push my code to github, will the older versions with the sensitive information be available? Or does it only push the current version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, even though you deleted it, older versions of the sensitive files will still be available. Use [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) to purge all versions of those files from the repo.

Answer (score 2):

If you committed the files with the sensitive information, then yes. The entire repository from your machine will be copied to github - and every file you have ever committed is in the repository on your machine.

If you want to keep the whole history on github except for those files, you can use `purge`. Or, you could start a new repository based on the current state of the files.

Comment: +1 I would recommend just reinitializing your git repo as well.